# accounting lettering algorithm to find matching amounts

Tags: algorithm

Do you know resources or links who talks about lettering algorithms ?

I need to find positives amounts that matchs with negatives ones to do lettering. For example :

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'debit' => NULL,
    'credit' => '440'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'debit' => '880',
    'credit' => NULL
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'debit' => '440',
    'credit' => NULL
  ),
)
```

here, indexes 0 and 2 can be associated with index 1, baut i can have more complicated associations

more examples :

```
     DEBIT        CREDIT
1       20         
2                     20
3       40

result => 1 / 2

     DEBIT        CREDIT
1       20         
2       40             
3                     40

result => 2 / 3

     DEBIT        CREDIT
1       20         
2       20         
3                     20
4       20

result => 1 / 3

     DEBIT        CREDIT
1       20         
2       20         
3                     20
4                     40
5       20

result => 1-2-5 / 3-4
```

thanks

Comment: sorry about my ignorance but I can't find any (satisfying) definition of lettering on the web. May you please clarify what you refer to? Regarding the matching amounts, do you have to find all the matching sums? the maximum of sums (such that the number of unmatched indexes are minimal), what else? EDIT: or if you are sure that the balance is 0, the minimal number of transactions (of the debitor to give back to creditor)

Comment: i did a google translate sorry. i need one result who gives the maximum of matches that can be found. i added somme examples of results i want

Comment: in your examples there is (at least) a missing case. If you have debits ```(5)``` and credits ```(5, 2, 2, 1)```, the matching should be ```5/5``` or ```5/2-2-1``` ? (or you don't care as long as the left over sum is minimal)

Comment: 5/5 because if there are several matches, the firsts matches takes precedance over the others